# erro ao rodar o comando npx react-native run-android

Tags: typescript, react-native

Criar um novo projeto em react native com tamplete em typescript e ao rodar o comando yarn android ou mesmo o npx react-native run-android eu to recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
error Failed to start the app.
Error: spawnSync adb ENOENT
   at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1041:20)
   at Object.spawnSync (child_process.js:616:24)
   at Function.module.exports.sync (/home/thayller/Developer/estudo/rocketseat/gostack 
11/appgobarber/node_modules/execa/index.js:334:30)
  at tryLaunchAppOnDevice (/home/thayller/Developer/estudo/rocketseat/gostack 
11/appgobarber/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform- 
 android/build/commands/runAndroid/tryLaunchAppOnDevice.js:57:22)
 at /home/thayller/Developer/estudo/rocketseat/gostack 11/appgobarber/node_modules/@react- 
 native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:104:39
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at runOnAllDevices (/home/thayller/Developer/estudo/rocketseat/gostack 
11/appgobarber/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform- 
  android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:102:48)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
   at async Command.handleAction (/home/thayller/Developer/estudo/rocketseat/gostack 
11/appgobarber/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Alguem que ja tenha passado pelo mesmo ou que entenda oque ocorre para me ajudar, pois eu ate o momento não descobri

Comment: Da uma olhada no PATH e verifique se o caminho para o Android SDK está presente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eu executei o comando:

```
npx react-native doctor
```

que me retornou o seguinte log:

```
Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ yarn

Android
 ✖ JDK
  - Version found: 1.8.0_252
  - Version supported: >= 8
✓ ANDROID_HOME
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 - Versions found: N/A
 - Version supported: 28.0.3

Errors:   2
```

Em base disso eu reinstalei o android studio, e reconfigurei as variaveis de ambiente e isso funciono.

Answer (score -1):

você instalou os pacotes do projeto?
roda `yarn` na raiz, pra baixar o node_modules
depois roda `yarn ios` ou `yarn android`, pra rodar seu projeto

Caso não dê certo, pode ser que não tenha o SDK do android instalado,

Comment: sim os pacotes são instalados inicialmente, isso ocorre no exato momento que build tenta instalar no emulador / celular o projeto